# Donald Duck comic book with giant shark

Tags: story-identification, comics, donald-duck

I seek help identifying a circa 1960 Disney comic book in English, where Donald Duck goes down in a diving bell.  A seemingly megaladon-sized shark attacks the bell, and the diving bell falls to the seafloor and into a really giant clam. The diving bell is covered with nacre, and then is found and raised.

Everyone thinks it is the biggest pearl ever found until Donald breaks out.

Comment: I assume it wasn't a [baby shark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179998/sing-baby-shark)....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My sons have recently been reading the reprint volumes of Carl Barks' *Donald Duck* and *Uncle Scrooge* comics.  Although the eleven-year-old initially informed me that this is "[Lost Beneath the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney_comics_by_Carl_Barks)" from 1963, I have now checked, and the correct story is **"[A Descent Interval](https://inducks.org/story.php?c=W%20WDC%20177-01)."**. First published in June 1955, it is collected in volume 15 of the Disney Ducks anthologies, *The Ghost Sheriff of Last Gap*.

Here is the shark.

[image: Shark]

And here is the "pearl."

[image: Nacreous Sphere]

Comment: [In case you want a picture to edit in...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8osl.jpg)

Comment: Jenayah's picture shows that "A Descent Interval" is the one with the diving bell mistaken for a giant pearl.